# Starting: Intent { cmp=com.MainActivity } and response error code 500 React Native

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

**Hi, I'm a beginner with React Native, while running react-native run-android, this error was returned.**

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 15.473 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Running /home/gustavo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s XXXXXX reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Starting the app on XXXXXXX (/home/gustavo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s XXXXXXX shell am start -n com.aa/com.aa.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.aa/.MainActivity }

**but nothing works**

before it worked.

I already uninstalled the app from my phone.

I've run the command "adb -s XXXXX reverse tcp: 8081 tcp: 8081"

I already deleted the folder node_modules and executed the command "sudo npm install"

I believe it is on the cell phone as it started to happen this after having done some biuld over wifi.
Does anyone know what can it be?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eow8.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRk2K.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the development server with `npm start` in your project.

Make sure that the app is already installed on your phone, so it can communicate with the dev server.

Comment: That's likely the problem. He is running `react-native run-android` but not `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error.

Try `MyApp> cd android` then `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

**I tried fixed that
write this in terminal**

1  `cd android`
2 `./gradlew clean`
3 `./gradlew assembleDebug`
4 `npx react-native start`

Answer (score -2):

Check the output of the terminal window running the development bundler. It’s likely you just have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks you. But, this acontece when i starting the project
react-native init myApp
cd myApp
react-native run-android

Comment: @gustavodelfim have you checked the bundler output anyway. The error screenshot indicates that the error details will be displayed there.

Comment: @gustavodelfim this "acontece" because you have to open two terminals, for instance, one with the development server and the other one to run the app